# How to define the column type of a data frame as date?

Tags: r, date, dataframe, rstudio

I would like to initializes a data frame (without any original entry) with several columns, one being of type date. The data frame is initialized and new entries will be inserted via rbind later on.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to specify Date as a type, let alone how to declare its format.

```
df <- data.frame(Date=Date(format="%Y-%m-%d"),Value1=integer(),Value2=integer())
```

But I cannot pass beyond this error

```
Error in Date(format = "%Y-%m-%d") : could not find function "Date"
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `as.Date(character())`, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                 Value1=integer(),
                 Value2=integer())
class(df$Date)

[1] "Date"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lubridate` with a template:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=lubridate::ymd(),Value1=integer(),Value2=integer())
sapply(df, class)
```